# Does it make sense to have using statement inside class constructor?

Tags: c#, constructor, dispose, using-statement

I mean using the statement below, inside the constructor of my class I use `FileSystemWatcher` instance, does it make sense to have `using` statement inside class constructor like this or it must be inside constructor without `using` statement?

```
public partial class MyService : ServiceBase
        {
            FileInfo file;
            StreamWriter writer;
            FileSystemWatcher watcher1;
            FileSystemWatcher watcher2;
            FileSystemWatcher watcher3;

            public MyService()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                file = new FileInfo(@"D:\LOGS\Log.txt");
                writer = file.CreateText();
    //I mean this using
                using (watcher1 = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\"))
                {
                    watcher1.Created += OnChanged;
                    watcher1.Deleted += OnChanged;
                    watcher1.Renamed += OnRenamed;
                    watcher1.Changed += OnChanged;
                    watcher1.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                }
    //I mean this using
                using (watcher3 = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\Users"))
                {
                    watcher3.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
                    watcher3.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite |
                                            NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
                    watcher3.Created += OnChanged;
                    watcher3.Deleted += OnChanged;
                    watcher3.Renamed += OnRenamed;
                    watcher3.Changed += OnChanged;
                    watcher3.Filter = "*.*";
                    watcher3.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                }
     //I mean this using
                using (watcher2 = new FileSystemWatcher(@"D:\"))
                {
                    watcher2.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
                    watcher2.Created += OnChanged;
                    watcher2.Deleted += OnChanged;
                    watcher2.Renamed += OnRenamed;
                    watcher2.Changed += OnChanged;
                    watcher2.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Are you using them outside the constructor and how?

Comment: Yes watcher instances can be used outside the constructor, the question is using statements are needed inside constructor or not.

Comment: No. `using` will dispose the objects immediately. You need to retain the references and dispose the objects later, explicitly, when you are sure you don't need them again. See marked duplicates for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep all this FileSysteWatcher instances non-disposed while your service is running. But you also should dispose all resources when service is disposed. So the best solution is to implement `IDisposable` by your service and dispose all resources in the `Dispose` method.

```
public partial class MyService : ServiceBase
{
    FileSystemWatcher watcher1;
    FileSystemWatcher watcher2;
    FileSystemWatcher watcher3;

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            watcher1?.Dispose();
            watcher2?.Dispose();
            watcher3?.Dispose();
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Consider also to move initialization logic to `OnStart` method of service. Or at least enable watchers on service start and disable them on service stop:

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        base.OnStart(args);

        watcher1.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        watcher2.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        watcher3.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        base.OnStop();

        watcher1.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        watcher2.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        watcher3.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
    }
```

Note: don't forget to dispose `writer` as well.

Comment: Can you see my last answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Sergeys answer is already good, I just want to add some more theory.

In general, you should using only with variables declared in the using, like

```
 using(var watcher = new ...)`
```

cause the variable is destroyed/disposed at the end of the using parenthesis. So never use it on fields or properties. Using is just a shorthand writing, to do a Dispose at the end, also in case of exceptions are raised. If you don't want to create and destroy you variable within the same method, you can not use 'using'.

With your approach, the watcher is disposed/destroyed, but it's not set to null. So it will cause strange behaviour. To avoid this, the variable in using should just not exist outside the using, it should be out of scope, that's why you declare the variable inside a using scope.

There are two patterns with Disposables. Either you use it with "using" to create/destroy it within the same method, or you include in in a disposable class. You create it inside a class, and dispose it, when the owning class is being disposed. On the owning class you apply the same rules again, maybe the owning class can be used with a using block.
Sergeys implementation assumes, your outside class is derived from a class already implementing IDisposable.